# How can I access a website on a Local Network in an OSX environment

Tags: macos, apache, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

So I have a website that I created locally but I would like to have other team members access it. I would also like to test my site using my iPhone for testing purposes. Th thing is when I check the Xip.io (LAN only) option (shown in the image below) a URL is displayed in the empty box below it. The problem is that when I use that URL the Xip.io URL in the browser of my iPhone. Nothing displays. Is there an easier way to make my website accessible from other machines locally? Is there a file that I need to edit or are my changes correct?

Thanks

Update
I'm using my internal IP. I can access my site with my laptop but other computers connected to my network cannot access my website. I figure that maybe I need to make a change to my httpd.conf file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution!  Since I'm working in OSX

Here are my steps:

- Go to System preferences Selected Network
- Select Wifi (since I'm connected via Wi-fi)
- Clicked on the Advanced button
- Click on the TCP/IP Tab
- Copy or write down the IPv4 Address:

Then

- Go to to PHPAdmin
- Select the database tab
- Select your database
- clicked on the *options* table
- under option_name  Change both values (*siteurl* and *home* ) in column *option_value*  to the IPv4 Address you copied from System preferences
- Opened MAMP Pro
- entered the same IPv4 Address in the Host IP Address Field
- Restart server

Helped me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you can use the app [Fing - network tools](https://www.fing.io/) on your phone to scan the network and get all IP addresses on it, your computer should be one of them (on regular protection networks).

What I think what happened is that that URL is not resolved correctly on other devices, you are probably giving them your *external* ip, try to use the app I mentioned, find your computer and attempt to connect to the IP address you find in that app. That IP will be your `internal` ip address, which is what you need.

Comment: I am using my internal IP.